# Extending Team Explorer 2015+ via VSIX

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, vsix, team-explorer

I want to know, if support for extending Team Explorer in "newer" Studios was changed significantly or not. I want to add a new section to the "Pending Changes" page in Team Explorer 2017.

Based on the informations [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn201751.aspx) I implemented a base class for this stuff:

```
public class TeamExplorerBaseSection : TeamExplorerBase, ITeamExplorerSection { ... }
```

and then derived from it:

```
[TeamExplorerSection(SectionId, TeamExplorerPageIds.PendingChanges, 900)]
public class MyNewSectionSection : TeamExplorerBaseSection
{
    public const string SectionId = "8AAE3BBE-E5FE-4D9E-9244-EA86F67B8512";
}
```

This worked in VS 2013 without any problem. When I hit F5 at least the Experimental Version of VS 2017 will not show any new section in the desired page.

What made me suspicios is that you can find nearly every needed component via NuGet from Microsoft now. As you can see [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundation/11.0.0) Microsoft had support for Team Explorer via NuGet too but for some reason decided to stop it at VS 2013. Another clue is that the official [VSIX-docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/starting-to-develop-visual-studio-extensions) will say nothing on this kind of extension.

Does this mean that one should not extend Team Explorer anymore?

Comment: Extending Team Explorer still works the same as it did in prior Visual Studio releases.  Are you building against the 15.0 version of the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls assembly?

Note that the NuGet package that you reference was not an official Microsoft package.  It was created and uploaded by a user.

Comment: I also provided sample base classes in the Extending Team Explorer sample that I built for VS 2012.  You can find that here:  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Extending-Explorer-in-9dccd594

Comment: @ChadB Thanks. The package author is Microsoft but the owner is some user. The project site is linked to the MS docu. But you are right he's probably not from MS. Hard to see sometimes on NuGet :-).

Comment: @ChadB I'll try your sample in 2017 and come back with the result.

Comment: The ITeamExplorer* interfaces live in an assembly that is versioned to match the major VS version.  That's the way all TFS assemblies are versioned.  This means that supporting an extension in a new major VS version requires a recompile against updated TFS assemblies.  Otherwise, the extension won't be discovered by MEF since the type's version will be old.  In hindsight, it would've been nice to freeze the version of the types, but that ship has sailed at this point.

Comment: I managed to bring it to work. It was all about versioning of the assemblies (like @ChadB) mentioned and the problem that I had a Nuget named `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.All`which somehow broke everything.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted out!  Sorry about the annoying recompile requirement for each major VS version.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in my case was to remove a NuGet package named `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.All` from my references. This package is outdated which I've not noticed.

The package situation for VSIX is somewhat annoying to me. I ended up building my own NuGet package containing the packages I need for VS 2015, VS 2017 and so on. This way I'm not depending in searching and referencing on the local machine which can break everything because we're working as a team using VSTS.